# jquery sortable handle IE vs Firefox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, handle

i'm trying to use jquery to implement a portlet/widget style interface, with 3 columns and drag and drop within and between them.  it's working almost completely, except for the following little bug.  the portlets have a header, h2, that i've set as the handle in my sortable options.  in firefox and chrome, this is working exactly as expected.  in IE, only the text of h2 serves as a handle until i actually move the portlet once.  then the entire header behaves as expected.  is this a bug, or am i missing something?  my code is as follows:

```
    $('.column').sortable({
        connectWith: '.column',
        handle: 'h2',
        cursor: 'move',
        placeholder: 'placeholder',
        forcePlaceholderSize: true,
        opacity: 0.4
    })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

got it working - had to put a zoom: 1; on the css for the class that serves as the handle.